# Omega Theme Region Disappear

Tags: views, blocks, users, theming

I have created a omega sub theme. In header first region I have put a views slideshow banner which was working fine but all of a sudden it disappears from anonymous user. I tried to put some other blocks in that region but not thing is showing up for anonymous user, but when I am logged in it shows banner and the blocks in that region.

Any idea ???

Comment: Are you using the same theme as admin ? Could be a misconfiguration of the sub theme, could you post your subtheme.info contents ?

Comment: Are you sure your view does show any content if the user is logged out?

Comment: other blocks are appearing in the region but views of banner content type is not appearing for anonymous users

Comment: I was displaying field from unpublished node, changing that to published starts displaying the banners. I don't know why it was happening I have done it in several other sites never faced this issue